# How to update column name after finding the table names from information schema

Tags: sql

I have run a script to find the table names with a specific column name from a database using the information schema
here is the query

```
  use IMS_SCMS_DIGITAL_POWER 
  select * from information_schema.columns
  where column_name like 'COMPANY_ID%'
```

after finding the table names now i would like to update the specific column values of all the database. Need solutions.

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using?

Comment: MSSQL. Also here is another problem "use IMS_SCMS_DIGITAL_POWER select * from information_schema.columns where column_name like 'COMPANY_ID%'" this query return some view table which i don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Run following query to get all tablenames with specific column name

```
SELECT t.name AS TableName
FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name LIKE '%COMPANY_ID%'
```

just use in forward only cursor with tablenames to update the specific table.